# Silent notifications except for one app

Tags: samsung, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-9, silent-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy s9+ device and I was wondering if it is possible to use the silent mode and still receive sound notifications from one app only?
I want to hear whenever I receive a Telegram message and have all the other notifications for other apps only appearing in the notifications bar, but without any sound.

Comment: Enable DND and add Telegram to exception list.

Comment: I don't find any application exception in the DND mode. I only see exceptions for calls and messages. Also, if assuming it would work, wouldn't that stop the notifications for the rest of the apps for good? I only needed the sound stopped.